# How to add class if content date is today?

Tags: javascript, date

I have a schedule calendar om my website, and want to make the current day stand out from the other days by using css to add a red border (just a example). I would probably need to use JavaScript to determine if the content is the current day. I have been trying to do this, but mostly guides out there are using data-date, so that makes me stuck.

The html output looks like this

```
<span class="date-display-single" property="dc:date" datatype="xsd:dateTime" content="2019-02-28T11:30:00+01:00">28.02</span>
```

How so i add a class if the content="2019-02-28T11:30:00+01:00", is today.

thanks.

Comment: So you mean that you want to highlight today´s date in a calendar by adding css?

Comment: Yes Lolpez, that is pretty much what I'am trying to achieve.

Comment: The content of the span is not a full date, do you really want to use the *content* property?

Comment: Take care in spelling JavaScript. http://javascriptisnotjava.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) to find the current day and month, which is a very valuable tool. The if statement checks to make sure the date and month are in mm/dd format. Then you can use [DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) to get the value of your html element ([innerHTML](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp)). Then finally, you can use [`.className`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_classname.asp) to add the class you wanted to the element.

```js
var d = new Date();
var month = d.getMonth() + 1; //.getMonth() is 0-11
var day = d.getDate();

if (day < 10) {
  day = '0' + dd;
}

if (month < 10) {
  month = '0' + month;
}

if (document.getElementById("day").innerHTML == `${day}.${month}`) {
  document.getElementById("day").className += " today";
}
```

```css
.today {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
```

```html
<span class="date-display-single" id="day" property="dc:date" datatype="xsd:dateTime" content="2019-02-28T11:30:00+01:00">23.02</span>
```

Comment: @jan no problem. You might have to change my code a bit. If it works for you, make sure to accept the answer so others know it worked as well

Comment: Thank you, id did work with your code snippet, but the problem is that my html only render span class, and not as an Id class. Is is anyway to target the span instead of id.

Comment: I updated my snippet to work for your code. Simply add the id to your element.

Comment: Ok i got it worked here https://jsfiddle.net/cprtkhmd/, thank you very much

Comment: @jan no problem. Good luck!